# Can a landlord break a fixed term contract before it becomes a monthly basis, without giving notice?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

I have a rental agreement with my landlord with a fixed period of 1 year. It states in the contract that this will automatically become a month by month basis, subject to cancellation under the same clauses that the fixed period was under, after the 1 year period is up. These cancellation clauses state that either side must give a certain amount of notice before cancelling the agreement.

I've been informed by the company that handles my property that they want another fixed contract rather than letting the contract become a month by month one. They've heavily implied I have no options other than to comply and sign a new fixed term agreement, and that the contract will not become a month by month one. I can't see anything that gives either side the option of cancelling this provision, so I'm not sure if legally they can do this. I don't want to sign up for another full year.

Are they allowed to do this?

Comment: Are they giving the proper amount of notice? It is hard to say without seeing the actual contract.

Comment: They haven't given any notice, they appear to want me to either move out at the end of the fixed term, or to sign a new fixed period contract.

Comment: How long until the 1 year is up? It sounds like they can legally tell you either sign another year or move out as long as they do so with enough notice. So, I suggest you tell them that you would like to go to month to month as the contract allows and if they do not want that, to provide notice in writing within the timeframe required by the contract.

Comment: The contract ends in just over 1 week. I feel like they've waited until the last possible moment in an attempt to fluster me into signing a new contract. At no point in our entire tenancy have they ever said or suggested they would not honour the automatic conversion.

Comment: Does the contract state that the notice must be done in writing? In a lot of places there are groups you can contact about landlord tenant issues that will give free consultation.

Comment: @mikeazo: notice periods for the most common type of tenancy are governed by law, and can't be restricted regardless of what the contract says. A landlord **must** give at least 2 months' notice. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: It may be in the interests of the agent to make you or someone else sign another year contract as they get another full commission. If you go onto the rolling contract, they may get less commission. If you can, try to contact your landlord directly find out why they don't want you to move onto a rolling contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an assured shorthold tenancy, [it will automatically become a "rolling" tenancy](http://england.shelter.org.uk/get_advice/private_renting/ending_a_tenancy/renewing_your_private_tenancy) (formally, a statutory periodic tenancy) when the fixed term expires, unless a new tenancy agreement is signed.

You are not obliged to sign a new agreement, and the landlord can't force you to. If you do nothing, you will have a rolling tenancy. If the landlord isn't happy with that, his only option is to [serve a section 21 notice](http://england.shelter.org.uk/get_advice/eviction/eviction_of_private_tenants/eviction_with_a_section_21_notice) to request that you leave.

(Incidentally, notice periods are governed by law, and so any cancellation clauses cannot "[take away a right a tenant might otherwise have had](http://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2012/11/21/contractual-periodic-tenancy-question/)". The default is that the landlord must give 2 months' notice, and the tenant one month.)

Comment: They've served me a notice, I have two months to vacate. Guess they were hoping I would just leave when they initially contacted me, realised I wouldn't and then took the two month hit. Not great, but at least I have more than half a week to leave now.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. From what you've described, the letting agency is either incompetent or unethical. Hopefully the next one will do a better job. Good luck.

Comment: It might be worth asking them if the landlord would accept a six-month contract rather than a year (even at this stage).

Comment: Loosely related: http://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2017/06/05/dont-sign-new-tenancy-agreement-renewal-fee-clause-will-evicted/

Answer (score 0):

Since the contract becomes a month-to-month lease automatically, preventing this from happening would require cancelling the contract. If the contract stipulates that they must provide you appropriate notice to cancel the contract, then that's what they must do.

I would suggest you ask them explicitly whether they wish to cancel the contract or not. Heavily imply that they have no other options other than to cancel the contract or not cancel the contract.